# How to find variance in Linear mixed models on this R example

Tags: self-study, mixed-model, random-effects-model

I have this linear mixed model with random intercept and slopes and the exercise ask to compute the `Var(Yij|bi)` and `Var(Yij)` at time point j=0, j=1 and j=2 (I'm not sure with the correct calculation of the second one).

`model7<-lme(Y ~ group*time, random= ~1+time| ID,data=datalong, method="REML",na.action=na.omit)`

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
  Data: datalong 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  834.5395 862.2162 -409.2698

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 + time | ID
 Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization
            StdDev    Corr  
(Intercept) 3.1548522 (Intr)
time        0.1852790 -0.029
Residual    0.8152861       

Fixed effects:  Y ~ group * time 
               Value Std.Error  DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept) 80.13241 0.8012907 200 100.00417  0.0000
group        1.13141 1.0637314  35   1.06363  0.2948
time         0.11699 0.0504998 200   2.31658  0.0215
group:time   0.05198 0.0674459 200   0.77066  0.4418
 Correlation: 
           (Intr) group  time  
group      -0.753              
time       -0.084  0.063       
group:time  0.063 -0.085 -0.749

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-1.94321191 -0.61990241 -0.06124059  0.53517425  3.25115453 

Number of Observations: 239
Number of Groups: 37
```

```
getVarCov(model7)

Random effects variance covariance matrix
            (Intercept)      time
(Intercept)    9.953100 -0.016846
time          -0.016846  0.034328
  Standard Deviations: 3.1549 0.18528
```

I compute the `Var(Yij)` at time 0 like this:

```
uncond_var_t0<-(sigma(model7))^2+ getVarCov(model7)[1,1]
```

I compute the `Var(Yij)` at time 1 like this:

```
uncond_var_t1<-(sigma(model7))^2+ getVarCov(model7)[1,1]+1*getVarCov(model7)[2,2]+2*1* getVarCov(model7)[1,2]
```

But my professor for the `Var(Yij)` at time 2 have suggested this code:

```
uncond_var_t2<-(sigma(model7))^2+ getVarCov(model7)[1,1]+4*getVarCov(model7)[2,2]+2*2* getVarCov(model7)[1,2]
```

I think that this is not the right solution and I replace that 4 with 2. Is this solution correct?

And i also ask if someone can explain me the difference between `Var(Yij|bi)` and `Var(Yij)`.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sidenote: *"ask to compute the `Var(Yij|bi)` and `Var(Yij)` at time point j=0, j=1 and j=2"* this term `Yij` is not very clear. You would use different formula's depending on whether `Yij` is an estimate or whether it is a prediction (a new measurement). Your problem seems to be the latter case based on the formula that you (and your professor) give as an answer, but from the problem statement itself this is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think that this is not the right solution and I replace that 4 with 2. Is this solution correct?

use the formula

$$\text{Var}(aX+bY) = a^2\text{Var}(X) + b^2 \text{Var}(Y) + 2ab \text{Cov}(X,Y)$$

When the time is 2 then the coefficients ($a$ or $b$ depending on how you apply the formula) will end up as squared in the formula and get a factor 4 on the right hand side of the equation.